# Output populated in next row and not overwrite existing row in VBA loop procedure

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have the following loop within my Excel VBA code:

```
 'Loop through all tickers
    For ticker = firstTickerRow To lastRow

        tickerSymbol = Worksheets("Port").Range("$a$" & ticker)

        If tickerSymbol = "" Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If

    'Get financial data from Yahoo and write into each sheet
    'getCookieCrumb() must be run before running getYahooFinanceData()
    '***************************************************
    Call getYahooFinanceData(tickerSymbol, startDate, endDate, frequency, cookie, crumb)
    '***************************************************

NextIteration:
    Next ticker
```

The output shows up as a single row, i.e. the data is overwritten over the loop and only populates that single row. However, my intended output is shown in the second table whereby the data populates the next row with no overwriting.

The error is within the subprocedure `getYahooFinanceData()`, which contains the following output code:

```
'Write results into worksheet for ticker
Worksheets("Port").Range("$B$4").Resize(UBound(resultArray, 1) + 1, UBound(resultArray, 2) + 1).Value = resultArray
```

I tried replacing `.Range("$B$4")` with `.Range("$B$" & ticker)` to make the output location dynamic but this does not work. There is run-time error '1004', probably because `ticker` is not found within the sub-procedure `getYahooFinanceData()`

How can I amend my code to ensure that the correct output with no overwriting is produced?

Current output with overwritten data

```
+--------+----------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| Ticker |   Date   |    Open     |  High  |     Low     |    Close    |  Adj Close  | Volume  |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| MSFT   | 4-Feb-20 | 1457.069946 | 1469.5 | 1426.300049 | 1447.069946 | 1447.069946 | 3933000 |
| GOOG   |          |             |        |             |             |             |         |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

Intended output

```
+--------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Ticker |   Date   |    Open     |    High    |     Low     |    Close    |  Adj Close  |  Volume  |
+--------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| MSFT   | 4-Feb-20 |  177.139999 | 180.639999 |  176.309998 |  180.119995 |  178.231873 | 36433300 |
| GOOG   | 4-Feb-20 | 1457.069946 |     1469.5 | 1426.300049 | 1447.069946 | 1447.069946 |  3933000 |
+--------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Yes, ticker is not a parameter passed to getYahooFinanceData. tickerSymbol is the range in column A so replace Worksheets("Port").Range("$B$4") with tickerSymbol.offset(0,1) to get the corresponding column B range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. pass `ticker` into `getYahooFinanceData` as an extra parameter `sub getYahooFinanceData (..., byval ticker as long)`
2. To position the output correctly, add `.offset(ticker-1, 0)` to the statement

```
Worksheets("Port").Range("$B$4").offset(ticker - 1, 0) _ 
    .Resize(UBound(resultArray, 1) + 1, UBound(resultArray, 2) + 1).Value = resultArray
```